# Accessing the trigger of the colorpicker

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm using the following jquery color picker on my project - www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker. I'm using multiple colorpickers on the same page, calling the script on a class ( I have 7 inputs on which the color picker is applied and none of them are related ). The problem I'm having is that I can't access the trigger as there is no relation between the colorpickers and their triggers.
Does anyone know how to do this? Basically I'm trying to use this function

```
(...)onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
     $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
}
```

Where $(this) should be the parent, but obviously it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the function to a context , 
so before calling the function , declare that

```
var that = this // or whatever this(the context) is
```

then call that in the callback instead of this.

```
...)onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
     $(that).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
}
```

EDIT : here is the javascript code i would write.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorpickerHolder').each(function(o) {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).ColorPicker({
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {

                _this.style.background = '#' + hex;
                // the input which is trigger the colorpicker is supposed to be $(THIS);
            }
        })
    })
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/camus/PQDf8/4/

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. Here ( [link](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about) ) are some examples and I'm trying to use the last one, but in the example the trigger is and ID ( which makes it unique on the page ), not a class.

Comment: i cant answer you precisely if i dont know what your code exactly is.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/r6vh8/) of my code. That's pretty much the essence of it :)